# How hooks (plugins) and different phases in chart.js works?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs-2

I read the documentation for chart.js plugins & about different phases like render,init,update available [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) that occurs while chart appears on browser.

But yet it is not clear for me how these different phases & hooks works.
And which hook to use when while making changes in chart.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do so people can actually help you

Comment: can you please click on the link & go down to flow chart where the different phases given like chart initialization , update.I was not clear about how these phases actually works with the plugins.